# Is this body in "Jessica Jones" a character in "Daredevil"?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv, jessica-jones

In *"Jessica Jones"* episode 11 AKA I've Got the Blues Jessica and Trish search for the body of an old man.

In the first morgue they visit the morgue technician says:

> Weird thing. He got hit by a car and thrown. The landing killed him.
>   You don't see that much mid-city. Speeds are too low.

It's around 11 minutes in.

I think this dead old man is Leland Owlsley who was killed in *"Daredevil"* by Wilson Fisk who threw him down an elevator shaft.

I couldn't really match the face of the corpse, the contrast on my TV isn't great. I can't find anything on IMDB or the other usual wikis etc.

Is it the same character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering the real-time aspect of the Marvel Cinematic Universe, Owlsley died on April 7th. Jessica Jones happens between DareDevil Season 1 and Season 2, November 2015 ish. There's no way for that body to be Owlsley, as it would have decomposed way before this. The body in the morgue is pristine, likely a day or two at most.

But they obviously meant to imply it to be. Notice the profile of the face in the morgue:

[image]

And Owlsley when he was still alive:

[image]

[image]

Not sure if it's video magic, or a look alike, but **Noticeably the eyes of the dead body are set much lower compared to the bridge of the nose, and the [Aquiline nose hook nose bump/curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquiline_nose) is missing, so it can't be Bob Gunton**. There is no source online that says this is an actual cameo either, so it's just meant as a (bad) easter egg universe building attempt.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I didn't know there were established dates for both series, shows how much attention I pay!

Comment: @ThrowingSpoon Daredevil has a very set timeline. I can't find any dates in Jessica Jones other than "a while After DD S1". Luke Cage, which will air in 2016, is also set a few months after JJ S1, nearly real time. The Avengers movies are also nearly real time, with Ultron being 3 years after Avengers.

Comment: @ThrowingSpoon also, check this post http://screenrant.com/jessica-jones-easter-eggs-netflix-marvel-mcu/?view=all specifically the crime den one. The fire bombing of Hells Kitchen happened in March 2015. And Sergeant Mahoney. He's in both series.

Comment: We're fairly confident that Jessica Jones happened in-universe way before November 2015; there are a lot of things that line up better if it's happening in late winter/early spring 2015: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108331/when-is-jessica-jones-season-1-set

Comment: Cool, maybe the timelines do fit then.

Comment: @mike your linked answer says tail end of 2015... and if it was 2014/early 2015, because owlsley and the fire bombing didn't happen until late April and march respectfully

Comment: It says "I'd estimate that the show takes place at the very tail end of Winter 2015", which i admit is confusing, but means around February (possibly into March) of 2015. It also says that *Jessica Jones* takes place **before** *Age of Ultron*, though how much before is pretty vague. The biggest clue is that episode 2 takes place "about a year" after Jan 2014.

Comment: @mike yet the first episode of DD takes place around March 9 when Baby Vamp Jessica is framed. So your implying that JJ starts before DD, and likely ends during the events of Season 1, which makes the March fire bombing of hell kitchen and Owsley April death, and Matt donning of the Red suit happen after JJ ends.

Comment: I dunno why but we got a strong impression that Daredevil takes place in late 2014, about two years and some change after *Avengers*

Comment: (note: I'm not commenting on if that is/isn't Owlsley; I think it's hard to line the timelines up to make that work.)