# Which comes first chronologically, Jessica Jones Season 1 or Daredevil Session 2?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, chronology, daredevil-tv, jessica-jones

I see that a character from Jessica Jones, Hogarth appears in the last episode of Daredevil Season 2.

Also the name "Jessica Jones" is mentioned in one of the episodes of Daredevil Season 2.

Which "event" comes first, Jessica Jones Season 1, or Daredevil Season 2?

Comment: See the comments here http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45471/is-this-body-in-jessica-jones-a-character-in-daredevil

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as we can tell, the Netflix shows are taking place in the same order they air, but several months "behind" real-time.

The shows are extremely vague on their timelines, but *Jessica Jones* appears to take place sometime in January or February of 2015, based on their description of the January 2014 accident as "a year ago", which puts it just prior to the events of *Age of Ultron*. *Daredevil* Season 2 appears to take place starting in either late August or early September of 2015, based on the unexpected heat wave, but clearly ends on Christmas that year. So *Daredevil* starts roughly 6 months after *Jessica Jones* ends.

Note that there are at least 3 references/callbacks to *Jessica Jones* in *Daredevil* season 2: the nurse makes a reference to Luke Cage being hard to injure, Foggy's girlfriend makes a reference to Jessica Jones being a powered person, and Hogarth shows up at the end to hire Foggy. None of those *necessarily* mean that *Jessica Jones* came first but they strongly imply it; especially since both Jessica and Luke were trying very hard to hide their powers before the events of that show.

Comment: (downvoter: did I miss and/or misstate something?)

Comment: I agree with your synopsis. It's also the way I saw it as well. I thought there might have been a few more parts in DD-S2 where they were talking more definitively about things which happened in JJ-S1, but I don't remember them off the top of my head (I was thinking about this while watching). The overlaps made sense.

Comment: The DA who appears in the last episode of Jessica Jones season 1 (played by Michelle Hurd) is killed in Daredevil season 2. That places DD2 after JJ1. (Late response. I just hadn't noticed this question before)